# sqlite3, бд создаётся только поле закрытия tkinter, как это исправить?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

После нажатия в `tkinter` на кнопку Vk, файл bd не создаётся моментально, а только после закрытия `tkinter`. Как это исправить?

Мне нужно, чтобы я мог создавать много разных файлов bd по нажатию на кнопки.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os  

def script():
    os.system('py')
    os.system('script.py')
    return
root = tk.Tk()

root.title('Парсер')
root.geometry('500x250')
root.resizable(False, False)

lable1 = tk.Label(root, text='VK', bg='red')
lable1.pack()

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='VK', command=script)
btn1.pack()





root.mainloop()



####################################  script.py


import sqlite3 as sq



with sq.connect('VK.bd') as con:
    cor = con.cursor()

    cor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id int auto_increment, name varchar)')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать? То, что написано после `root.mainloop()` - это что?

Comment: `con.close()` ?

Comment: Отредактируйте тело вопроса. Оформите код так, чтоб было понятно, что это два разных файла. Это делается за несколько секунд. Для этого используется язык разметки Markdown, вы обязаны его знать, если хотите быть программистом; он используется повсеместно.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, первое.
Вы не добавили `con.commit()` и `con.close()`, а это значит, что изменения в БД не сохранятся, а также БД не закроется.

Ну и второе.
У вас что такое `root.mainloop()`? Это бесконечный цикл, который позволяет окну Tkinter не закрываться а висеть, пока его не закроют. Соответственно он кончается, когда вы закрываете окно, *и только потом* выполняется всё, что *стоит после `root.mainloop()`. Поэтому предлагаю вам перенести `root.mainloop()` в самый конец... На будущее, `root.mainloop()` *практически всегда* должно стоять в самом конце.

Comment: script.py это другой файл а не продолжение первого, как я по вашему его передаю ? , root.mainloop() стоит в конце. читал что con.close() не обязательна если работает через with

Comment: Коммит обязателен))

Comment: Где вы вызываете файл??

Comment: Уточните вопрос..

Comment: в pycharm, оба файла в одной директории

Comment: @Михаилmilk из документации `Connection object used as context manager only commits or rollbacks transactions, so the connection object should be closed manually`